# Using grep to export specific lines to new files reiteratively

Tags: linux

I have a folder with many files. I want to go into each file and export lines that are more than 80 characters.

I'm using

```
grep '.\{80\}' filename > newfilename
```

But I want to do this for all files in the directory at once. How can I do this so that I have the same number of files?

Comment: Is `grep` a must?

Comment: Plus: you say "more than 80 characters" but your code also matches 80.

Comment: The specific code doesn't matter. I need a loop that will do this to many files and write the results in different output files. I don't want the results appended in one file.

Comment: cross-posted https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446941/72456

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12817971) `sed` can filter lines by their length:

> ```
> sed -e '/.\{120\}/!d'
> ```
>
> […] matches lines that don't have (at least) 120 characters (the `!` after the expression is to execute the command on lines that don't match the pattern before it), and deletes them (ie. doesn't print them).

`sed -i` works in place. This leads to a following approach:

```
cp -a original_dir/ modified_dir/
find modified_dir/ -type f -exec sed -i -e '/.\{80\}/!d' {} +
```

Now every file from `original_dir/` has its modified version in `modified_dir/`.

Alternatively you can work totally inside the `original_dir/`, telling `sed` to save old files with a suffix:

```
find original_dir/ -type f -exec sed -i.old -e '/.\{80\}/!d' {} +
```

In this case if you use `-i` instead of `-i.old`, the old files will be lost.